# Writing multiple directories to the desktop c#?

Tags: c#

```
public static void CreateFolder()
        {
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory); //Gets desktop folder
            string pathTo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/" + "SYS_" + Random6CharString() + "/"; //Creates random directories
            foreach(char path in Random6CharString())
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTo); //Method to create folders on Desktop
            }
        }
        public static string Random6CharString()
        {
            string path = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            path = path.Replace(".", ""); // Remove period.
            return path.Substring(0, 6);  // Return 6 character string
        }
```

I'm making a game, and it should write folders to the users desktop to use as events on the game. When I get to a point, where 2 folders should be created simultaneously, it only creates one folder. Can anyone tell me how to make more than 1 folder at once? Or at least do them one after another instead of simultaneously? Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to play a game that creates folders on my desktop.

Comment: It's nothing new, it just doesn't use a game directory folder and uses something more 'personal' I guess you could say.

Comment: If you use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you don't have to worry about the path separator characters.

Comment: @TAYLORBROWN - If you need a personal folder you could use the SavedGames folder under the user's tree:  `C:\Users\username\Saved Games` or under the user's AppData folder: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local`

Answer (score 1):

```
string pathTo = ...
foreach(char path in Random6CharString())
{
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTo); //Method to create folders on Desktop
}
```

You're using `pathTo` instead of the `path` variable of your `foreach`. So you're trying to create two folders with the same name in the same location (which it doesn't by the way, `CreateDirectory` can't overwrite an existing folder).

Comment: `path` is a `char`, so I wouldn't recommend passing that to `CreateDirectory` either.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
       string pathTo = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "/" + "SYS_" + Random6CharString() + "/"; //Creates random directories
        foreach(char path in Random6CharString())
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathTo); //Method to create folders on Desktop
        }
```

You're creating `pathTo` twice.

You could easily generate a random value for the path by using `System.Guid.NewGuid()`, by the way.